# When execute "AudioKit.start()", an error occorent

Tags: swift, audiokit

I have push the recordViewController that record audio by AudioKit from homeViewController which is an emptyViewController，and I have write code in APPDelegate.swift like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}catch{

}
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
return true
}
```

then when it push to recordViewController,show this message

> ```
> '[AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1266:Initialize: (err =
> AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph,
> kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(),
> isOutputChainActive)): error -10875,
> RecorderViewController.swift:stetupConfigs():89:AudioKit did not
> start!'
> ```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem like sufficient information to debug your problem.